# Moving cursor away from dropdown button causes it to change colour

Tags: html, css

Every time I press the Login dropdown menu, the colour of the button is inheriting the background image's colour. However, when I move my cursor away from the Login button, a white square appears over it. I do not have any css supporting the button. Both the code and sample images are below. I am trying to make it so that when I move my cursor away, the Login button still inherits the background image colour rather than changing to a white square.
Amateur at bootstrap coding so if there are any other mistakes, do let me know!

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b><span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
```

[Cursor is on button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV6d2.png)

[Removing cursor from button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st9dI.png)

Comment: Sounds like you have an `active` or `focus` style somewhere that's breaking your layout, but without a reproducing example we won't be able to help any more than giving vague suggestions.

Comment: If you use bootstrap probably your button inherit style from bootrstrap css. Use chrome inspector the active and focus state.

Comment: The issue is that when I use chrome inspect, the "issue" does not occur for some apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

Happens because when you click on the dropmenu bootstrap adds a class called `open` to the `<li>` which applies that background, and it stays until it loses focus all you have to do is override that class and remove the background.

add this to your css file which should come after the bootstrap `<link>` to override it.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover{
    background:none;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your input however, placing the code you wrote into my css file which I linked under the bootstrap file doesn't seem to solve that issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: It works fine for me with bootstrap 3.3.7, Which bootstrap version you using ?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 too

Comment: Add `background:none !important;` and see